# If $f(a+3) = x(a+4)$, what is $f(a+2) - f(a+4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $f(a+3) = x(a+4)$, what is $f(a+2) - f(a+4)$?

How could I go about approaching this problem?
All I am starting off with is replacing $a+3$ by $b$, thus giving 
$f(b) = x(b+1)$, and then having to find $f(b-1) - f(b+1)$. But this is just a way of making the problem look friendlier.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $x$ ? A constant?

Comment: Also, I guess, what is $f$? Usually read as a function, but then maybe $x$ is a function too?

Comment: @Joffan In my answer, I assumed that $f$ is a function and that $x$ is a number, but I really don't know.

Comment: Both are functions, I think. This is as much information as I have as well actually. Question doesn't have anything else.

Comment: Actually, x being a number makes more sense. Thank you. Out of curiosity, how would you treat the problem if it was a function?

Comment: @stellarhawk34, in that case, since we've no more information about the function $x$ than given by $f(a+3)=x(a+4)$, we can only conclude that $f(a+2)-f(a+4)=x(a+3)-x(a+5)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(a+3)=x(a+4)$:

$f(a+2)=f\bigl((a-1)+3\bigr)=x\bigl((a-1)+4\bigr)=x(a+3)$

and

$f(a+4)=f\bigl((a+1)+3\bigr)=x\bigl((a+1)+4\bigr)=x(a+5)$.

So$$f(a+2)-f(a+4)=x(a+3)-x(a+5)=-2x$$(assuming that $x$ is a number, not a function).

Comment: This is what I would have answered too.  I don't think there is any other possibility given the lack of information about $a, x, $ etc.  Anyway, nice job given what we have to work with!

Comment: Assuming $x$ is a constant, I think it's enough to say that $f(a+3)=x(a+4)\overset{t=a+3}{\iff}f(t)=x(t+1)$ from which we conclude that $f(a+2)-f(a+4)=x(a+3)-x(a+5)=-2x$